# Translating a /etc/network/interfaces syntax to NetPlan and NetworkManager

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu

I have the following directive saved in /etc/network/interfaces which has been working fine. It binds the same IP address 192.168.1.202 to both of my en and wl adapters:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
    post-up /sbin/ip addr add 192.168.1.202/32 dev lo
```

1. What's the equivalent YAML syntax I could use with Netplan?
2. What would be the equivalent syntax to load it to NetworkManager?
3. If (2) is possible, is there a text file (rather than a GUI) which would have an editable plain text file representation of the configuration

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you cannot use NetworkManager directly with loopback as it's specifically excluded from it.

The only way I found to solve this is to have a hybrid Netplan/NetworkManager solution which worked.

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    lo:
      renderer: networkd
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [192.168.1.202/32]
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers: 
        addresses: [192.168.1.1,8.8.8.8]
```